# Grade ranges in excel and show blank ones

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to return blank for the empty rows but it still evaluates differently.

```
12     B
222    C
442    Not listed
121    C
       A
122    C
3455   Not listed
```

I am using

```
=IF(B3<10,"A",IF(B3<100,"B",IF(B3<300,"C",IF(ISBLANK(B3),"Blank","Not listed"))))
```

The blank line still shows `A`

Comment: Because you will hit `TRUE` on your first `IF`. A blank cell will evaluate to `0` which is smaller than 10

Answer (score 1):

Alternate version using Choose/Match:

```
=IF(B3="","Blank",CHOOSE(MATCH(B3,{0,10,100,300}),"A","B","C","Not Listed"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Test for blank **first**:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),"Blank",IF(B3<10,"A",IF(B3<100,"B",IF(B3<300,"C","Not Listed"))))
```